# Add metadata in powershell script for uploading files

Tags: powershell

I have a current script which upload different .rdl files to my sharepoint site and in to different folder. E.g below:

It looks like this:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "mysite" 

$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Reports"]

$file = [io.file]::ReadAllBytes('D:\temp\test.rdl')

$spList.RootFolder.SubFolders["Test"].Files.Add("test.rdl",$file)
```

Now I would like to add data as well.
E.g Datasource, Type, Credentials etc.

Anyone who can help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

get the item by file and update the metadata of the file

```
$tFile = $folder.Files.Add("test.rdl",$file)
$tItem=  $tFile.Item
$tItem["Title"]="title1"
$tItem.Update()
$tFile.Update()
```